# Heroku Application Error Hello_App from Ruby on Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm in the deployment section of the first chapter of the Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I can't make things work! I'm using the Cloud9 workspace.

My Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug', '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring', '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

My Heroku installation log is:

```
-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.1

-----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7

       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.

       Old: ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [x86_64-linux]

       New: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...

       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

       Using rake 10.4.2

       Installing minitest 5.7.0

       Installing i18n 0.7.0

       Installing builder 3.2.2

       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5

       Installing mini_portile 0.6.2

       Installing erubis 2.7.0

       Installing rack 1.6.4

       Installing mime-types 2.6.1

       Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1

       Installing arel 6.0.2

       Installing json 1.8.3

       Installing execjs 2.5.2

       Installing thor 0.19.1

       Using bundler 1.9.7

       Installing multi_json 1.11.2

       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3

       Using rdoc 4.2.0

       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4

       Installing tilt 1.4.1

       Installing sass 3.4.16

       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2

       Installing rack-test 0.6.3

       Installing sprockets 3.2.0

       Installing mail 2.6.3

       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1

       Installing uglifier 2.5.3

       Installing sdoc 0.4.0

       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2

       Installing activesupport 4.2.0

       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3

       Installing globalid 0.3.5

       Installing activemodel 4.2.0

       Installing jbuilder 2.2.3

       Installing activejob 4.2.0

       Installing activerecord 4.2.0

       Installing pg 0.17.1

       Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2

       Installing loofah 2.0.2

       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.6

       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2

       Installing actionview 4.2.0

       Installing actionpack 4.2.0

       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.2

       Installing actionmailer 4.2.0

       Installing railties 4.2.0

       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0

       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3

       Installing rails 4.2.0

       Installing sass-rails 5.0.1

       Installing turbolinks 2.3.0

       Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 51 gems now installed.

       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

       Bundle completed (35.52s)

       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

       Could not detect rake tasks

       ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present

       and using the production group of your Gemfile.

       rake aborted!

       NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::Script

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/Rakefile:4:in `require'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'

       /tmp/build_e66783d527b235cf6db9221a52037d9b/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'

       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'

       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'

###### WARNING:

       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types -> (none)

       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 29.1MB

-----> Launching... done, v6

       https://lit-caverns-5466.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

When I open the link I get the message:

```
Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Comment: "If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

Answer (score 0):

Does your app run successfully in `production` mode locally ? If not try to run your app locally in production mode and you might be able to spot the issue.

```
bundle install --without development:test
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

Comment: I could fix problem on exercise 1. Now on exercise 2 (toy_app) i'm having the same problem... works fine in development mode. EDIT: Don't know the exact procedure to fix ex.1 xD

Comment: were you able to run your in `production` mode locally ?